# Select 2 in Rails not rendering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, select2-rails, collection-select

I am trying to implement select2 functionality in my project. It is not rendering properly. I am pasting my code, please tell me where it went wrong

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="userInputCollegeName">College Name</label>
              <%= f.collection_select(:college_id, College.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select the college'}) %>
            </div>



<script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user_college_id").select2({theme: "bootstrap"});
});</script>
```

In my html the id for the collection_select is `user_college_id`.

I am adding an image:

[image]

I know that the first select is because of collection_select tag and the second field is because of select2, but I dont need the first one.

I only require the select2 field. How can we do that? Any help is appreciated thankyou!

Comment: can your share the generated HTML code?

Comment: `<select class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" required="required" name="user[college_id]" id="user_college_id" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Select the college</option>


<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-user_college_id-container">


<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-user_college_id-container" title="Select the college">Select the college</span>`

Comment: Sorry For pasting like this

Comment: are there 2 different select tags there?... There might be some problem with your rails code then.. and can you try using just `$("#user_college_id").select2();` to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: How can I just use that, the user_college_id is generated from the collection_select tag. I just need  how to implement the select2 tag in html from a collection i.e retrieving it from a table (here college table)

Comment: Please check out the answer given bellow

Answer (score 0):

there might be problem in your

```
f.collection_select(:college_id, College.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select the college'})
```

try changing it to

```
f.collection_select(:college_id, College.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select the college'}, {class: "user-college-select"})
```

and inside your `javascript`:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".user-college-select").select2({theme: "bootstrap"});
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The collection_select cant have more than 6 parameters passed. Its showing an error. I removed :user parameter and tried the code you gave, its not working

Comment: Forget about the question. How to create a search drop down with contents retrieved from a table. i.e using select2

Comment: @saitejareddy can you show the complete code of the view and controller

Comment: and dude have you included the the `select2-bootstrap-theme` `select2-bootstrap.css` ?

Comment: @saitejareddy it's in the gem but is it included in your application layout?

Comment: like mentioned in [README.md](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails/blob/master/README.md) of the gem.

Comment: @saitejareddy I made a sample project to test out `select2-rails` myself.. it works perfectly fine.. you can checkout my [repo](https://github.com/mubashir93/select2-test)

Comment: @saitejareddy you can have a look at `views/posts/_form.html.erb`, `assets/javascript/application.js` and `assets/stylesheets/application.css` and of course the `GemFile`...