# How to implement select2 gem with contents retrieved from a table in Rails (association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select2-rails

I am trying to implement select2 rails gem in my project. But it is not rendering properly.

My question is, I have a table called college which consists of a list of colleges. I want to implement drop down with search using select2 gem.
I need to how to call the select2 from the form. When I use collection_select, I am getting two dropdowns, one of collection_select and other from select2.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You should provide more info with your code. Add your implementation of collection_select and select2 javascript. You are probably not calling select2 on your collection_select form but creating another one next to it instead if it's loading 2 dropdowns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565689/select-2-in-rails-not-rendering-properly/34565948?noredirect=1#comment56895135_34565948